# I Am getting this as an error message in android studio Android resource linking failed Error?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-resource-qualifiers

This is an error which is showing when I import the project. It is showing `gradle invocation failed` but after that when I started copy-pasting each xml and java file then it is showing me this as an error message !!

```
Android resource linking failed
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6040: error: resource color/purple_500 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_500) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6041: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_700) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6042: error: resource color/white (aka com.example.android.pets:color/white) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6044: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/teal_200) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6045: error: resource color/teal_700 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/teal_700) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6046: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.android.pets:color/black) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6040: error: resource color/purple_500 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_500) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6041: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_700) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6042: error: resource color/white (aka com.example.android.pets:color/white) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6044: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/teal_200) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6045: error: resource color/teal_700 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/teal_700) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6046: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.android.pets:color/black) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:36: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_200) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:37: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_700) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:38: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.android.pets:color/black) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:40: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/teal_200) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:41: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/teal_200) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:42: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.android.pets:color/black) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:36: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_200) not found.
com.example.android.pets.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:37: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.android.pets:color/purple_700) not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem a while ago.
paste this in color.xml, the file needs this to start the program, you probably deleted this by accident

```
  <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
  <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
  <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
  <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
  <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
  <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
  <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
}
```